# storing MIME type with blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How can I also store the MIME type of incoming blobs to the blobstore? I now neither get the name nor the MIME type stored which using the handler `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler` it can. Here's my code that doesn't use `blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler`:

```
    def create_image(number, self, file, ad):
        logging.debug('creating image')            
        try:
          file_name = files.blobstore.create()
          with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
              f.write(file)
          files.finalize(file_name)
          blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
          logging.debug('creating image')
          img = Image(reference=ad) 
          logging.debug('creating image')
          img.primary_image = blob_key
          logging.debug('creating image')
          img.put()
          ad.put()
        except Exception:                
           self.response.write(Exception)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both name and mime type can be passed as arguments to create:

```
def create(mime_type='application/octet-stream',
           _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=None):
  """Create a writable blobstore file.

  Args:
    mime_type: Resulting blob content MIME type as string.
    _blobinfo_uploaded_filename: Resulting blob's BlobInfo file name as string.

  Returns:
    A file name for blobstore file. This file can be opened for write
    by File API open function. To read the file or obtain its blob key, finalize
    it and call get_blob_key function.
  """
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I notice it's done automagically when using the spec blobstoreuploadhandler. I think I can use that instead since I don't know how to get the MIME type or filename. The I'd have to change my form posting which I supposse I can do.

Comment: You can grab the browser-specified filename and mime type from the cgi.FieldStorage object. If you're using an upload form, though, using BlobStoreUploadHandler certainly makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I searched for cgi.FieldStorage and couldn't find exactly how to do it. I will try again find how to do it with cgi.FieldStorage or do it with a BlobStoreUploadHandler